# html5 player not playing

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to use VideoJS in a website I'm developing (http://videojs.com/), however I'm trying to load a simple YouTube video on the page for testing purposes but still not working:

```
 <div class="video-js-box">
            <!-- Using the Video for Everybody Embed Code http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody -->
         <div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 600px; display:none">
            <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
              preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="my_video_poster.png"
              data-setup="{}">
              <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehjDXDVpLgo" type='video/mp4'></source>
              <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehjDXDVpLgo" type='video/webm'></source>
            </video>
            <!-- Download links provided for devices that can't play video in the browser. -->
            <p class="vjs-no-video"><strong>Download Video:</strong>
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehjDXDVpLgo">MP4</a>,
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehjDXDVpLgo">WebM</a>,
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehjDXDVpLgo">Ogg</a><br>
              <!-- Support VideoJS by keeping this link. -->
              <a href="http://videojs.com">HTML5 Video Player</a> by VideoJS
            </p>
          </div>    
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div><!--main-->
```

And on the  of the page I have:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
```

Any clues what's going wrong here? I was expecting to be able to load and play that video on my page.

Comment: Your youtube links are links to the HTML page not to the video source or the swf file.

Comment: I did link to a .ogg file:
`<source src="/Users/philipperibeiro/dev/ci/videos/MVCH_11-05-11.ogg" type='video/ogg'></source>
`

Comment: Could you also post your code sample for the video hosted on your site?

Comment: @philippe - No you did not. (at least in the code you posted up there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Youtube video to test videojs, since it's hard to find a direct link to the video source. Check this out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag).

The code your provided links to the youtube page not to video source.

```
<source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehjDXDVpLgo" type='video/mp4'></source>
```

The video source might be hidden [in here](http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/watch_as3-vflbPspVE.swf) but I'm not sure. Use your own videos hosted on your site to test.

But if you still want to use youtube videos then check out the [Video.js forum](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/suggestions/28-ive-fixed-youtube-support-for-videojs), where someone provides code for a workaround.

An easier way to embed youtube videos would be to click the "share" then "embed" tab under a video page and copy and paste the code on your site.
Which would give you something like this.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gZKXrLjCwa8"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Also I would suggest reading the Video.js documentation again on [how to setup](http://videojs.com/docs/setup/).