# How to Embed Youtube Videos into HTML5 <video> Tag?

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api

I am implementing site where i required to embed youtube videos into  tag in HTML5. 
can you tell me how should i embedd into this without using `<iframe>`

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag

Answer (score 8):

There's no way to do this without Javascript. But the wonderful MediaElement.js library will work wonderfully for this purpose:

http://mediaelementjs.com

The example above shows using a YouTube video with a `<video>` tag, but also has a fallback to Flash for browsers that don't support it.

Comment: `mediaelementjs` It also using iframe, any other way??

Answer (score 6):

You can't extract the source of the video without violating YouTube's terms of service.  The only supported way to embed a video in a web page is using the iframe embed.

Comment: Can you attach a source ?