# Link to YouTube video in HTML5 <video> tag

Tags: html, video, youtube

Is there a way to use a YouTube video link in the `<video>` 's `source` tag so that I do not have to download the video file and upload it to my server?

I wan to play a YouTube video as a background on my site so I do not want to use `iframe` embeds because this technique would require some quirky hacks to hide the video player controls and prevent users interacting with the video (pausing, starting, etc.).

Having the video embedded in the `<video>` tag would be the best approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube URL in Video Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836015/youtube-url-in-video-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awesome **[Plyr](https://github.com/Selz/plyr)** package and install it via

NPM, bower, Ember or use a CDN

- It's semantic (  tag )
- Responsive
- For Youtube and Vimeo
- Written in "vanilla" JavaScript ( No libraries dependencies )

and **the total weight is less than 60 Kb** totally acceptable.