# How to embed YouTube video without CSS3DRenderer in three.js

Tags: three.js, google-cardboard

Is it possible to embed YouTube video without CSS3DRenderer in three.js? I'm using cardboard effect, So CSS3DRenderer won't work here.

Here is the code that i used so far. But im facing cross domain issue

```
video = document.createElement('video');
video.autoplay  = true;
video.src = 'http://myurl.com/videos/video.mp4';
newcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
context = newcanvas.getContext('2d');
videoTexture = new THREE.Texture( newcanvas );
.....
```

In animate function i have used the below code.

```
if (video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA ){
    context.drawImage(video,0, 0);
    if(videoTexture)
        videoTexture.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to embed your youtube video in an html video tag. If you have a look on the internet you'll find a lot of ways for doing this. This may come useful to you: [YouTube URL in Video Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836015/youtube-url-in-video-tag)

After having this working you need to convert it to a `THREE.Texture`, so you can map it to a mesh and use WebGL Renderer. There's a `Three.js`extension for this: [threex.videotexture](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.videotexture)

Comment: I'm simply passing the cross domain url('http://myurl.com/img/videos/sample.mp4') in threex.videotexture. But the video is not playing.

Comment: here is the code i modified so far.
var canPlayMp4 = document.createElement('video');
 var url = "http://myurl.com/img/videos/sample.mp4";
 var videoTexture= new THREEx.VideoTexture(url)
 video = videoTexture.video;
 video.setAttribute('crossorigin', '');
 videoTexture.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
 videoTexture.texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
 updateFcts.push(function(delta, now){
  videoTexture.update(delta, now)
 })

Comment: Sorry I was not available, I've seen you posted another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883592/load-cross-domain-image-in-texture/36883867#36883867), hope that helped you

Comment: That one is for loading image texture. but im facing cross domain issue in video also.

Comment: I guess if you solve cross domain issue it should work. Let me know

Comment: I tried using https://crossorigin.me/http://myurl.com/img/videos/sample.mp4 for cross domain issue but its not working.  this method is working well for texture load.

Comment: DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded.

Comment: Try: video.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');

Comment: Or: video.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is working now.. But for crossorigin we need to use "http://cors.io/?u=http://myurl.com/video.mp4" and https://crossorigin.me/ is not working.

Comment: Is ther any other method is available other than adding http://cors.io/?u= or crossorigin.me because this both option having performance issue. it takes too much time to load a simple video file.

Comment: The reason why is slower it's because it goes through a proxy server. It's a bit like using Tor Network :) I don't think there's something to do unfortunately

Comment: I'm facing issue in another scenario. Previously i have uploaded the video file in separate server and trying to get data by "http://cors.io/?u=http://myurl.com/video.mp4" but in some case i have youtube embed url(https://www.youtube.com/embed/osS1NXMPwWE) by this time it is not working and not showing any error in console. I'm implementing the YouTube video in Video tag using http://jsfiddle.net/qpbsfxgr/

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible in praticle. Youtube.com will not accept any cross domain job with there assets. Only way is to use youtube API with iframe but i make some action to make this possible.

You will need to add server part for you web app. I use nodejs.

This is procedure:

- Use classic google , youtube APi login/search
- Make search and collect search result data (Most important is `videoId` )
- Save to your own server
- Call from web app your new route.

Now you can do what ever you want.

Direct demo link: https://maximumroulette.com:3000

https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/vue-typescript-starter