# Load cross domain image in texture

Tags: three.js

How to load cross domain image in textureloader and im getting "Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin..." error

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('http://myurl.com/img/box.png', onTextureLoaded);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First option**

Add a CORS header to the asset, permitting cross-domain requests:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

**Second option**

You can create a server side proxy, and then load the asset like this

```
loader.load('myproxy?url=http://myurl.com/img/box.png', onTextureLoaded);
```

However you need to be careful, as proxies can use up a lot of bandwidth and you need to be very thorough when setting it up so you don't accidentally open your server to some code injection attacks.

Comment: https://crossorigin.me
This service could help to use external sources, but make sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: Where i need to write CORS header in static html.

Comment: Wow @escapedcat thanks I didn't know that existed.
@VijayBaskaran do it like this: `loader.load('https://crossorigin.me/http://myurl.com/img/box.png', onTextureLoaded);`

Comment: thanks @escapedcat and molbal.. I got one more answer too same like escapedcat said. we need to use http://cors.io/?u= before the url for ex: loader.load(' http://cors.io/?u=http://myurl.com/img/box.png', onTextureLoaded);

Comment: Do u have any idea about adding cross domain video without css3DRenderer.?

Comment: That's a new question I would say :)

Comment: I do not know much about three.js unfortunately