# how to Use Video link as a source in html5 video tag

Tags: html, video, youtube

Can anyone here tell me how can i use the html5 video tag for youtube video ?
i am currently using

```
 <video width="100%" controls="controls">
 <source src="url" type="video/mp4" />
 <source src="url" type="video/ogg" />
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

please tell me any solution, I have checked the following link for solution but can't understand this

[Show Youtube video source into HTML5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Note:
I am using this code for mobile website.
Thanks,
Shah Rukh

Comment: check http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_video_tag.cfm

Comment: than why don't you embed the youtube video directly?

Comment: Thnx to both of you I used embed code, actually i was saving yourube urls in my data base and the url not working then i fatche the video ID frm that url and jst change it in the code.