# HTML5 - Opening youtube video in view player

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, youtube

Title says it all really. Is it possible to open a youtube video in an HTML5 video player? I want to play a youtube video in a way that is more mobile friendly and was planning on uploading a thumbnail and then creating a `onclick` function to open up the video in fullscreen - this is particularly important on mobile devices. I know that I could use the youtube iframe but find it a bit 'clunky' to use, especially on android. On iOS it at least autoplays the video in full screen - is there an option like this available on android?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed HTML5 YouTube video without iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726480/embed-html5-youtube-video-without-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

In general the answer is no - YouTube want you to use their player, their ads etc for obvious reasons.

There is quite a good overview of what can and can't be achieved for HTML5 players and YouTube, based on one of the biggest web players, JWPlayer, here:

- https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed

I don't think you are interested in a native Android App, but if you were then there is a specific YouTube API:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: Thanks Mick. I have setup a system that opens links in the youtube app now so think I'm sorted :)