# Replace Play Button

Tags: html, css, youtube

I'm currently learning HTML and CSS, and was curious how the classes work. So I made an page in HTML with a Youtube embedded video in it. Then using CSS I set this

```
.ytp-large-play-button-bg {
    background:url("bigplay.png");
}
```

This was supposed to change the play button with the image stored locally named bigplay.png

But it remained the the same play button. Can someone say what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example. Also use triple backticks for big code blocks, rather than single backticks.

Comment: I have hosted it here - [link](http://majordwarf.cu.cc/123/index.html)
I tried to change the Youtube play button by using it's class, I found the class via Inspect Element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube is embedded as an iframe meaning CSS placed on the parent page won't propagate down to it's content. This leaves you with two alternatives:

1. [Clone the iframe content to add your own styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)
2. [Embed youtube without using an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726480/embed-html5-youtube-video-without-iframe)

---

## Edit

Looking into option 1 I have attempted the following (using PHP to preprocess the iframe content and inject your CSS before serving the page): https://www.tehplayground.com/Hjk19qDWeiwIWkKl

It appears there are a number of security processes in place to prevent you from doing this.

If you are new to CSS and HTML as you say and are using this as a learning exercise this is certainly not a trivial task. I would highly suggest starting with some more basic exercises.

Comment: I tried the second option but still the CSS is not being applied. The Play button is is till the default, the one from Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I have inspect it and I changed these properties it's working. The play button is an svg so you need to hide it and change the parent with background play image. If I got you what you want.

```
button.ytp-large-play-button {
    background: url(bgimagesomethpath);
    height: value;
    width: value;
}

button.ytp-large-play-button svg { 
        display: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, and its not working. I can make it work if I do Inspect Element in Chrome or Firefox. But when I refresh the page its gone.