# How can I embed video from youtube using the url?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand the difference between video element and iframe.
I want to set the header with a video from youtube as background.

Why this is not working:

```
<header>
    <video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBIwiK7U9l0"></video>
</header>
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding a comment.

Comment: not use iframe. look it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726480/embed-html5-youtube-video-without-iframe

Answer (score 2):

You're linking a page and not a video.
On YouTube you can click on share and then embed it.
You'll have a workable iframe

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FBIwiK7U9l0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Can I style width and height with CSS? Can I do the same with video element?

Comment: The width and height are defined where I put width="560" height="315". As of the video tag, I think you can tweak it with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iFrame:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FBIwiK7U9l0"></iframe>
```