# I'm trying to make my iframe responsive, but I cant get the height to fit the TV border

Tags: html, css, responsive

I made this iframe so I could put the TV border over the video player, and so far I've been trying to make it look good on mobile, so far it looks good on PC browsers (jsbin displays it weird, but in the actual [site](https://manosantapost.com) it looks good), but I don't get the height of the video to fit.

```html
<html>
  <style>
    
    iframe {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      left: 12%;
      top: 34%;
      width: 60%;
    }
    
    #TVborder {
      position: absolute;
      float: center;
      z-index: 0;
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      pointer-events: none;
      }
      
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/tv/tv_PNG39278.png" width="100%" id="TVborder" />
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Id3tNsMj_hA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

What do you think would be the best approach to fix it?

Comment: The best approach is removing the iframe.

Comment: And what would you add instead of the iframe? @Leandro Bardelli

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726480/embed-html5-youtube-video-without-iframe

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player

Comment: Tried this but still having the same exact issue:

https://jsbin.com/xamaziqize/edit?html,output @Leandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a container around the iframe and tweaking that a bit, here's how the code went out:

```html
<html>
  <style>
    
    iframe {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #TVborder {
      position: absolute;
      float: center;
      z-index: 0;
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      pointer-events: none;
      }
      
   .embed-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
   .embed-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
      
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="embed-container">
<img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/tv/tv_PNG39278.png" width="100%" id="TVborder" />
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/622576121?h=92d4a4e5c6&amp;autoplay=1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:9%;width:66%;height:79%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```