# Get AudioContext from an <embed> object instead of an audio or video tag?

Tags: javascript, mediastream, audiocontext

I'm trying to get the audio context from an embedded YouTube video, but can't use an iframe because of cross origin requests being blocked. I found on the thread, ([Embed HTML5 YouTube video without iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726480/embed-html5-youtube-video-without-iframe)), that YouTube videos can be embedded using the object and embed tag. However, I can find no method after exhaustive searching to get an audio context from an embed source.

Example tag:

```
<embed src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Sdg0ef2PpBw" width="100%" height="333">
```

For example:

```
let element = document.querySelector("embed"); 
let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
let source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(element);
```

Would simply return "TypeError: AudioContext.createMediaElementSource: Argument 1 does not implement interface HTMLMediaElement."

Comment: let element = document.querySelector("embed") as HTMLMediaElement

Comment: What do you mean? How can I set it as HTMLMediaElement?

Comment: Exactly how I've written. Do you use TypeScript?

Comment: Oh, I haven't used Typescript before. I tried it in Typescript just now and got the same error "Argument 1 does not implement interface HTMLMediaElement." ex: https://jsfiddle.net/7q0xhc85/