# How can i embed youtube video into html5 <video> tag

Tags: html, video, youtube

Hi i am trying to embed the youtube video to html-5  tag

i got the embed code from youtube...

embed code:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/M4MNG4gaQZw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

i want to embed this video into html-5 video tag..

so i did like this in html-5.0 using video tag....

code:

```
<video  width="300" height="200" controls autoplay>
       <source src="//www.youtube.com/embed/M4MNG4gaQZw" type="video/mpeg" />
</video>
```

but when i run the html5 page in web browser it is showing

```
no video with supported format and MIME found
```

Comment: That youtube URL delivers an HTML document to be displayed in the iframe. Of course it makes no sense to feed the `video` element with an HTML document, it has no idea how to “play” that.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag

Comment: @Xyroid I tried that one...but didn't work for me...