# Is it possible to use YouTube video with HTML video tag?

Tags: html, video, youtube

I'm making website and I need to add video, but not using `iframe`. Video tag doesn't have this ability I guess, maybe there are some simple alternatives?

Comment: I think so, but you need to use a `javascript` solution, which acts as a wrapper - something like this might work : http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube

Comment: i think this may answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
    <title>HTML5 MediaElement - YouTube</title> 

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://mediaelementjs.com/js/mejs-2.13.1/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mediaelementjs.com/js/mejs-2.13.1/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>MediaElementPlayer.js</h1>

<h2>YouTube Wrapper</h2>

<video width="640" height="360" id="player1">

    <!-- Pseudo HTML5 -->
    <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI" />

</video>

<span id="player1-mode"></span>

<script>

$('video').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function(media, node, player) {
        $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + media.pluginType);
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

More info at http://mediaelementjs.com

Comment: Some things like volume managing and fullscreen just doesn't work. Idk why :)