# Affect a div when is out of view?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to affect a div that is out of view? Ex: when you scroll down the page and the div is no longer visible.

I have an embedded youtube video and I would like to mute it only when the video is no longer in view.

Comment: Capture scroll event and pause video...

Comment: @Joakim M this may seem trivial to you, but can you elaborate more? or post a code?

Comment: It seems Maurice got what you want!

Answer (score 0):

This will mute every video player that is not visible:

```
$(function() {
    var $w = $(window), oldw = 0, oldh = 0, oldt = 0;

    function checkVideoVisible() {
        if (oldw !== $w.width() || oldh !== $w.height() ||
                oldt !== $w.scrollTop()) {
            oldw = $w.width();
            oldh = $w.height();
            oldt = $w.scrollTop();
            var top = oldt, bottom = oldt + oldh;
            $("video").each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.offset().top + $this.height() >= top &&
                        $this.offset().top < bottom) {
                    $this.prop("muted", false);
                } else {
                    $this.prop("muted", true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Now to trigger the checking, you can either use a timer:

```
    var timerId = setInterval(checkVideoVisible, 200);
}
```

Or handle the scroll event:

```
    $w.on("scroll", checkVideoVisible);
}
```

In the latter case, you will also need to perform a check when any change is made to the dom.

Comment: sorry I'm such a noob, I don't really know javascript. I'm trying to get it working here http://jsfiddle.net/EGTbV/30/ I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: 1) I've used jquery, so you will need to include it in your fiddle, 2) the script is in the onLoad handler, which makes $(function() { redundant, 3) your video is in an <iframe>, and you have no control on the contents of an <iframe> with the source in another domain. Use a <video> tag instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag

Comment: Can't use video tag, unfortunately youtube made it that the video source url expires after x amount of time. Thus, I have to use the iframe way. What about using the mute from the youtube iframe API? https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#mute

Answer (score 0):

Use this as its probably your best bet im guessing as you;ve posted no code that a pre-written lib will help you

[JQ Visible Lib](http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-element-onscreen-visibility/194)

To implement you need to give your element an id and reference it in script tags or in a js file like this:

`$('#element').visible()` will return true if visible.

You can then add the part to mute/pause the video based on that state.