# restrict the size of video in a site

Tags: html, video, size

We are using following code to display video in a site.

```
<a width="300" height="300" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FEqXWwPFusI">
```

Video is displaying by covering entire monitor size.

If i click on menu_video.jpg image, it's displaying video with full size.

But I want to display the video for specific space. [width ="300" height="300" ]

Suggest me to find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
 <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FEqXWwPFusI" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use video tag . try this:

```
<video width="400" height="400" controls>
  <source src="video file" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video file" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. 

your solution did't worked, but it's really helpfull for me for learning....

Answer (score 0):

Try this code istead

```
<video width="300" height="300" controls>
  <source src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FEqXWwPFusI" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

[Source link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

or try iframe

```
<iframe type="text/html" 
    width="300" 
    height="300" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FEqXWwPFusI"
    frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

---

or [refer this question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag)

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. 

your's first solution did't worked, but second one is working fine....