# I have a playlist and I want to change volume on my blog

Tags: javascript

This is the playlist, I do not know where I have to put the volume change, I tested and does not work, please help.

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLZtfdXg51ABw32MoMvZRQdN_EX9NHZLC8&autoplay=1" width="200"></iframe>
```

Comment: please see my question and accept it if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do that, modifying an iframe doesn't work.

I recommend that you use the video tag. 
This gets a bit more complicated, but there are good answers for that:
[Show Youtube video source into HTML5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag)

When you have a video tag with the specific youtube video, you can then adjust the volume with javascript:

```
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
video .volume = 0.2; // 20% volume
```