# Embed video in an image in responsive html5

Tags: html, image, css, video

I'm trying to embed a video inside an image, the challenge is that the page is responsive. The video looks in place on full screen, however it moves out of the box when resolution changes.

So I want the video to be inside the image frame at all sizes. Should I use @media or is there another way?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" style="width:344px;height:780px"
        src="Images/mywork-images/cicis/cicis-mobile.jpg">
    <div class="player">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/139805324"
            width="290" height="290" frameborder="0"
            webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen
            allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div> 
</div>
```

```
.player{
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    bottom: 565px;
    left: 21.3%; /* 110px */
}
```

Comment: @imGaurav Can you give an example on how to embed a YouTube or Vimeo video using the HTML5 video tag?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag

Comment: don't forget to close your <img> tag

Comment: @kakajan `img` tags don't need closing in HTML5.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit the question: what box should the video go in? how does changing resolution/window size affect the video?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I can't upload images sorry. I have an iphone image and I want to play an Instagram video inside the iphone frame. The page is responsive so if I reduce the size of the page or view it on mobile, the video doesn't stay in the specific area. Is there a way to show you images?

Comment: Upload them to imgur, share the links here, and I'll update the question to add the images

Comment: @SexyTurnip don't know, thanks for info

Comment: @MuaathAli, did you try to use html5 responsive video players like [flowplayer](https://flowplayer.org), etc...

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro HYG http://imgur.com/a/G5meV

Comment: ok guys thanks for you help. I found a solution, the parent div should have a position relative and the child div should have a position absolute.