# How to detect click event of iframe for play video in HTML page in android app?

Tags: android, html, iframe, video, android-webview

Any one knows how to detect click event of play button of `iframe/video` in `HTML` which is loaded in web-view.

in HTML Page contains like

```
<p><iframe width="100%" src="youtube.com/embed/uxpDa-c-4Mc"></iframe></p>
```

and i need to detect click event of Playvideo button in android webview.

Comment: Please insert a snipped of your html showing on what you want to intercept events

Comment: in HTML Page contains like "<p><iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uxpDa-c-4Mc"></iframe></p>" and i need to detect click event of Playvideo button in android webview.

Comment: There is no way you can have access to an iFrame with contents from another origin. You may be able to cover the iFrame with a transparent div and track that but you will not be able to send clicks to the frame either

Answer (score -1):

Give the element an id, do the following in Javascript (I am assuming you have JQuery, your question itself is lacking details in many ways as I write this right now, you should really try to give more information in order to get answers).

EDIT: My solution to the iframe/jquery issue would be to use a video element instead of an iframe. Here is how: [Show Youtube video source into HTML5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag)

We would then continue to use the below JS/JQuery

Example JQuery:

```
$('play').on("click", function() {
    //Do something
});
```

Example with shortcut implemented:

```
$('play').click(function() {
    //Do something
});
```

Comment: currently in my HTML page contains like : <p><iframe width="100%" src="YOUTUBE URL"></iframe></p> and i need to detect click event of iframe (when i play video)