# Youtube without javascript and plugins

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'd like to use Youtube and watch videos completely without javascript and plugins. Is it possible to do this just by using HTML5 or something like this?

Comment: You want to avoid iframes? I've just added a link that can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Youtube video source into HTML5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag)

Comment: @IgnacioAra Yeah, is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: Then use the link above @delxa that uses <video> tag

Comment: @IgnacioAra Is there a way to watch videos directly on youtube website? Also without js and plugins

Comment: Here: https://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: @IgnacioAra And what? It just show me what my browser support

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168652/discussion-between-delxa-and-ignacio-ara).

Answer (score 0):

More at:

**[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp)**

`<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>`