# Youtube iframe picture-in-picture mode

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, picture-in-picture

I'd like to use JavaScript to enable PiP on Youtube videos. I am able to do so on html `<video>`s but it seems impossible to do so on Youtube `<iframe>`s. Has someone any lead on this?

Answer (score 7):

Users may be able to right click twice (to bring up the html5 menu) and select Picture in Picture, but it seems to be impossible to trigger it programmatically from outside the iframe due to the same origin policy for iframes. I don't imagine that the `&origin=` parameter in the iframe URL actually changes the headers sent from youtube, it didn't seem to work in my testing.
[SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

The youtube iframe api [gets around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html) by using postMessage, however there are no messages implemented at the moment to execute `video.requestPictureInPicture()`. There seems to be a `togglePictureInPicture` function defined inside the player base.js script but this doesn't seem to be exposed through the message passing API

Answer (score 4):

You **cannot** enable PiP programatically using Youtube's iframe embed. The only option is to get the URL directly to Google's streaming servers or stream the video data yourself. Either way you need a stream URL to set as the src for a video element, then call `video.requestPictureInPicture()` on the video.

```
https://r4---sn-4g5ednls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1627319351&ei=15...
```

Thats what a stream URL for a video hosted by google looks like. A guy name [Levi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag/64894396#64894396) wrote a [library](https://github.com/thelevicole/youtube-to-html5-loader/) to retrieve this URL for a given Youtube video. But the library makes request to his proxy server yt2html.com in order to retrieve this URL.

I go in more detail on the issues with YT PiP in this [blog post](https://dev.to/spankyed/enable-pip-on-youtube-video-embeds-2gel).

Answer (score 3):

I always use the next line in the console, on the youtube page:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video');
```

This will show a HTML Collection, open it and right click on the first position of the collection, store it as global variable, this will generate something like `temp1`. Then you have to write the next line:

```
temp1.requestPictureInPicture();
```

And that's it.

Comment: It would mean a lot to me if you could please elaborate how it can be done programtically from the text editor. This feature could drastically reduce the server load, and improve UX for my project.