# Chrome Extension to manipulate youtube videos

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I want to develop a chrome extension that can read the pixels of a youtube video and for example can swap all red pixels to blue ones.
After a little research i found that most answers are outdated.
all approaches i found started with getting the html5 video (and after that go on with canvas):
[Show Youtube video source into HTML5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag)

Would be very thankfull if you can help me:)

Have a nice day.

Comment: _After a little research i found that most answers are outdated._ = can you [edit] the question and add the results of your research?

Comment: did it:)i did add some results