# Force HTML5 youtube video

Tags: html, video, youtube

Regarding the [Youtube API Blog](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html) they are experimenting with their new **HTML5** Video Player.

Apparently to play a video in html5, you have to use the iframe embedding code :

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

But if the client has not joined the [HTML5 Trial](http://www.youtube.com/html5), the player will automatically fall back into the flash player even if the client's browser is HTML5 video capable.

How to force the HTML5 video playback if the browser supports it, even if the users are not yet involved in the HTML5 Trial?

Otherwise how to disable the flash fallback?

EDIT:

It's possible to force HTML player through [links to Youtube Video](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/08/watch-video-in-youtubes-html5-player.html), but I need this kind of feature for embedded videos.

Comment: What if you were to detect HTML5 Capability with js, and implement the youtube api code accordingly.  Or I should say, if HTML5 Video not supported, don't implement the youtube api as it would resort to Flash.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

I've found the solution :

You have to add the `html5=1` in the src attribute of the iframe :

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dP15zlyra3c?html5=1"></iframe>
```

The video will be displayed as HTML5 if available, or fallback into flash player.

Comment: hmm - now it's not working (same vids), weird.  I wonder if it only works on certain youtube servers?

Comment: Doesn't work when adding `&html5=1` to the end of a non-embedded video :/

Comment: Adding `&html5=1` (or `&html5=true` or anything like that) to the end of a hyperlink (not iframe embedded video) does not seem to work in IE without Flash.

Comment: YouTube videos with advertisements will automatically use the Flash player

Comment: @IvanCastellanos lmao epic link. Side note- it doesn't work under Firefox 20?

Comment: Adding `&html5=1` to the link worked for me in Firefox (for Android) and in Chrome. You can tell which version has loaded by right clicking the video.

Comment: I think all the reports are biased. 

Nobody said if he/she is in "html5 beta of youtube" and this is probably key factor.

When I leave the html5 beta, it seems that ?html5=1 don't do anything. Every video goes with flash.

Comment: without being on the html5 trial the &html5 doesn't work in chrome 29

Comment: I dont think adding html5=1 is working, though it's possible that just embedding you tube in iframe is doing the job

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/embed/dP15zlyra3c?html5=1 is still working as of November 5 2013

Comment: James's comment of youtube.com/embed/dP15zlyra3c?html5=1 does not work for me using the latest chrome on Win 8 sadly.

Comment: Does not work Chrome 32.0.1700.107 / Ubuntu 13.10. I have HTML5 beta enabled and most of videos are played in HTML5 version but not all and that's really weird.

Answer (score 20):

Whether or not YouTube videos play in HTML5 format depends on the setting at https://www.youtube.com/html5, per browser. Chrome prefers HTML5 playback automatically, but even the latest Firefox and Internet Explorer still use Flash if it is installed on the machine.

The parameter html5=1 does not do anything (anymore) now. (Note it is not even listed at https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters.)

Comment: Just checked, I have chosen the HTML5 player in https://www.youtube.com/html5, but if &html5=1 is not specified as a parameter to the embed player, flash is loaded, when I specify the param HTML5 player is loaded. OS: Linux, Firefox 33 64bit.

Comment: I just tested `html5=1` in Firefox 33.0.2 and it works well (and does not require that users enable the HTML5 setting on YouTube).  Without it YouTube sends the Flash version by default.

Comment: The parameter still works, but enabling it on the html5 page makes youtube default to html5 which is better.

Answer (score 4):

I tried using the iframe embed code and the HTML5 player appeared, however, for some reason the iframe was completely breaking my site.

I messed around with the old object embed code and it works perfectly fine. 
So if you're having problems with the iframe here's the code i used:

```
<object width="640" height="360">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?html5=1&amp;rel=0&amp;hl=en_US&amp;version=3"/>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
<embed width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?html5=1&amp;rel=0&amp;hl=en_US&amp;version=3" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"/>
</object>
```

hope this is useful for someone

Comment: YouTube `<object>` is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) as of the end of January. Use `<iframe>` instead.

Comment: `<object>` still works, in fact the iframe just contains it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the iframe embed API, you can put `html5: 1` as one of the `playerVars` arguments, like so:

```js
player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: '<VIDEO ID>',
    playerVars: {
        html5: 1
    },
});
```

Totally works.

Answer (score 0):

Inline tag is used to add another src of document to the current html element.

In your case an video of a youtube and we need to specify the html type(4 or 5) to the browser externally to the link

so add ?html=5 to the end of the link.. :)