# YouTube embed on iPad: Buffers forever when starting via Javascript API

Tags: ipad, youtube, youtube-api

I'm having some issues getting a YouTube embed to work.

I'm using the YouTube API to load the video. On top of the loaded video I have a custom controls `<div>` (transparent) with just a play button (an `<img>`). It is done in this way to hide the default YouTube player behind a play button that goes with the rest of the design on the site.

The `<div>` overlays the entire loaded iFrame, so the player itself is not clickable - I use a click event on the `<div>` to start the video instead:

```
// Inside onYouTubePlayerAPIReady():
var player = new YT.Player(playerId, {
  height: height,
  width: '100%',
  videoId: videoId,
  playerVars: {
    html5: '1',
    controls: '0',
    rel: '0',
    showinfo: '0',
    modestbranding: '1',
    theme: 'light',
    color: 'white',
    wmode: 'transparent',
    suggestedQuality: "large"
  }
});

$(".youtube-player-controls").bind("click", function(e){
  if (!player || !player.getPlayerState) return false;
  if (player.getPlayerState() == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) player.pauseVideo();
  else player.playVideo();
  return false;
});
```

Works fine on iPhone, but on iPad (and Android too it seems) the video switches to the first frame of the video, but then stalls at the buffering state (checked via `player.getPlayerState()`).

I tried starting the video with `player.loadVideoById()` which doesn't work either (same error).

If I remove the overlaying controls `<div>` and thus allow the user to actually click on the video it works fine.

Any suggestions as to how I can get the video to play using the Javascript API?

**Edit:**

I changed the embed code a little bit, i.e. I added the `html5=1` as described in [Force HTML5 youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845484/force-html5-youtube-video). This changes the contents of the embedded iFrame to use the HTML5 player, but does not solve the problem.

I tried it to see if it could work as described in http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html.

Comment: I too seem to encounter this problem as well. Video keeps on loading forever on iPad and even iPhone 4.

Comment: For me it actually works as intended on iPhone 4. Haven't been able to test iPhone 5.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. In my case it doesn't seem to be related to overlay on the controls, because my button is behind the video. Video loads, starts to buffer and sticks on black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Apple do not allow  tags to be loaded via scripts on iOS (to prevent using unnecessary  bandwidth while on mobile networks). Several versions of Android show the same behaviour.

You will have to get the user first initiate the video by clicking on the video itself - after that you will be able to control the video via the API as on desktop devices.

Comment: This only applies to preload/autoplay as described in http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html and can be circumvented using Javascript onclick event. This is, however, described for HTML5 audio/video embed, so it might not apply entirely to YouTube embeds (don't forget, something *does* happen when the custom play button is clicked).

Comment: While true for HTML5 <video> tags in the same DOM, this cannot be circumvented for the YouTube API as Apple does not pass the initiator of the script across window contexts.

Afraid I can't find a reference to this that I'm ok sharing, but it's been confirmed to me in person by the author of the YouTube iframe API.

Answer (score -1):

Currently we're just doing a check before sending in the player.playVideo(); function. It's not ideal but it works until we get a better API level fix from Google.

At top of the embed script you set your var:

```
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
```

Then in the click function you use:

```
if (!isiPad) {
player.playVideo();
}
```

Comment: Not playing the video isn't much of a solution.

Comment: @mikemaccana the solution is to route a different event to the ipad. So, in our case, we allowed for the click event to remove the poster frame and start the video via JS for supported browsers. For things like iPads we'd just remove the poster frame on click, and the user would click again to initiate the video. It's certainly not perfect but it works.

Comment: @jabberlope I'm not a big fan of detecting devices. Plus I'm seeing this on several different mobile devices (iPad 3rd Gen, iPod 5th Gen, Moto X). Is there a way to detect wether the playVideo() function or the portion that's not working correctly is supported?

  `if (!canPlayViaJS) {
    player.playVideo();
  }`