# Youtube embed video not working in android 4+ (Ice cream sandwich,Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, html5-video, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

This code works fine in android 2.2.But give protocol not supported error in android 4+ 
I refered this site https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

```
<html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
 <title>Vadivel</title>

<style>
body
{
background-color:#588DEA;
}
</style>
 </head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

<object width="320" height="430">
<param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/5whBYQVnjvY?modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=1"></param>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/5whBYQVnjvY?modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allownetworking="internal" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"  width="320" height="430">
    </embed>
</object>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Source: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html

Gonna need this: [Force HTML5 youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845484/force-html5-youtube-video)

Also see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: Got it working. I had to add `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});` and `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` for it to work properly. Did not need the class or type.