# video pop-up WITHOUT Flash

Tags: html, video, fancybox

I'm trying to create a video pop-up that works on Apple devices and I've been playing around with fancyBox & some YouTube videos. Because YT uses Flash, this isn't going to work (which I am just now realizing)

Is there a way to open up an html5 video inside of this pop-up?
I already set that part up:

Here's the page where I'm already using fancyBox: http://legal-replay.com/video-test/ 
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="iframe" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dP15zlyra3c?html5=1">Open HTML5 Video</a>
```

I don't know much about fancybox but it looks like you can just have it open any iframe you want, which will work with YoutTube's default embed method. Just pass `html5=1` to the iframe.

From what I can tell scouting around stackoverflow, this is only supported for single videos, I don't know if you can force an entire playlist to use HTML5, that might still be a client-preference.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845484/force-html5-youtube-video)

[Fancybox Howtwo](http://fancybox.net/howto)