# idangerous swiper prevents HTML5 play button working in ie10

Tags: swiper.js

I have an embedded HTML5 video which works fine in all browsers (or fails gracefully, if the browser is old or lacks video support). But since my site uses iDangerous Swiper (http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php), the custom video controls - the 'play/pause' button - does not work in Internet Explorer 10.

If I remove the swiper js code embed from the head area of my HTML, the embedded video plays fine in ie10. The problem seems to be that Swiper is intercepting the click on the play button in ie10 - and therefore the solution seems to be to disable Swiper for at least that small area of the page.

But it's not clear how to do it.

There seems to be a very scantly documented new feature in the June 2013 Swiper release which lets one create a 'noSwiping' class, but wrapping the video in a div with this class does not solve the ie10 problem.

Has anyone else needed to disable Swiper for an element and succeeded in doing so, particularly regarding ie...? I would be very glad to see a code example. My own project is still on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add the html5=1 in the src attribute of the iframe :

The video will be displayed as HTML5 if available, or fallback into flash player.

you can read this:
[Force HTML5 youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845484/force-html5-youtube-video)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with a embed video of youtube inside a dangerous swiper, but the solution of TSL works for me!

I had added the html5=1 and solve my problem!

thanks!