# HTML Bootstrap Modal Popup Youtube video

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using bootstrap modal popup to view the youtube video sharing in my webpage if i click video button bootstrap modal popup open properly in all browser. if i close bootstrap modal it closing properly except SAFARI browser
see the image difference. Tell how to solve

This is my code

```
<div class="modal fade pop_video" id="Product_video<?php echo $i; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog entp_product_video">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><strong>Product video</strong></h4>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div style='width:50%'>
        <?php if(!empty($row['product_vedio'])) {
        $pos = strpos($row['product_vedio'],"youtube" ) ;
        $pos1 = strpos($row['product_vedio'],"youtu.be") ;
        if($pos  != "" ) {
        $domain =   $row['product_vedio'] ; 
        $domain = str_replace('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','',$row['product_vedio']); 
        }
        if($pos1  != "" ) {
        $domain = str_replace('https://youtu.be/','',$row['product_vedio']); 
        }
        ?>
         <object id="yutb_video" width="570" height="275" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $domain; ?>"></object>  <br />

        <br />

        <?php } ?>
        </div>  
        <div id="clearall"></div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Screen shot link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a108l0ymq9gcx3w/img1.jpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3loq4bkdcte1ly/img2.jpg?dl=0

First link screen shot is After closing bootstrap modal popup

Second link screen shot is Before closing bootstrap modal popup

Comment: where are the screen shots?

Comment: I try to post screen shot but can't

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 and Youtube in Modal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622508/bootstrap-3-and-youtube-in-modal)