# some questions on youtube IFrame API

Tags: youtube-api

With IFrame API, whether a video is played with html5 container or flash container depends on a lot of factors. I'm wondering: is it possible to set some parameter or call a function to force the player to be flash(or html5)?

besides, rel=0 seems not work in Iframe API, when I set it to 0, the related videos are still shown, is there something wrong with my code? thanks!

```
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '300', //720
      width: '400', //1280
      videoId: 'S2Rgr6yuuXQ',  
      playerVars: { 'rel': 0 }, // or rel: 0, rel: '0', all don't work
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        'onError': onErrorDetected,
        'onPlaybackQualityChange': onQualityChange
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the iframe option does not include a parameter to select html5 or flash option , because the iframe API uses the best option automatically.

you can try to specify to use HTML5 if available:

[Force HTML5 youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845484/force-html5-youtube-video)

[YouTube video in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520113/youtube-video-in-html5?lq=1)

and you can use the SWFObject option to use only the flash player in the client (if the client supports flash ..)

Answer (score 1):

Using `playerVars: { html5: 1 }` loads an iframe with a `html5=1` attribute in the src, similar to [Force HTML5 youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845484/force-html5-youtube-video).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
playerVars: { 'rel': 0 }
```

with

```
playerVars: { 'rel': '0' }
```